# Django "local flavor" select widget in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want to use [in_.forms.INStateSelect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/localflavor/#india-in) in admin .

what filed should I add in model ? and how can I make it to show a widget in admin ?

**Edit**

*I am trying this*

```
from django.contrib.localflavor.in_.forms import INStateSelect
state = INStateSelect()
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you trying that code? A widget needs to be attached to a field...

Here's one way you could do this:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'my_state_field':
            kwargs['widget'] = INStateSelect()
        return super(MyAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
```

Another would be to override the admin form and use the `INStateField`

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['myfield'] = INStateField()


class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyForm
```